# jQuery 3.5.1 issue with .val() expressions in an OR chain

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why does the following snippet evaluate to TRUE? I have 2 empty fields and am checking their `.val()`. In **jQuery 2.2.4**, the following was correctly evaluating to FALSE, but when I switched to **jQuery 3.5.1**, it started evaluating to TRUE.

You can substitute 2.2.4 for 3.5.1 and see that it starts behaving differently.

```js
console.log($('#race').val());
console.log($('#gender').val());
if ($('#race').val() || $('#gender').val()) {
  console.log('Selections exist');
} else {
  console.log('Selections do NOT exist');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<select id="race" name="races" class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-select2-id="race" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="RACE_AI_AN" data-select2-id="41">American Indian or Alaska Native</option>
  <option value="RACE_ASIAN" data-select2-id="42">Asian</option>
  <option value="RACE_BL_AA" data-select2-id="43">Black or African American</option>
  <option value="RACE_NH_PI" data-select2-id="44">Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander</option>
  <option value="RACE_WHITE" data-select2-id="45">White</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="gender" name="gender" class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="gender" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="" data-select2-id="28">Gender</option>
  <option value="GENDER_MALE">Male</option>
  <option value="GENDER_FEMALE">Female</option>
  <option value="GENDER_OTHER">Another Designation</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I would checkout [mcve] as that will assist you the most at this point.

Comment: added snippet above

Comment: Read [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/val/). "As of jQuery 3.0, if no options are selected, it returns an empty array; prior to jQuery 3.0, it returns null."

Comment: Just a suggestion. You could have debug the code at the line of condition and check value of `$('#race').val()`. This way you can easily identify why your condition returns `true`. Or you can also add `console.log($('#race').val())` before `if` statement and check in value `console window`. This can save your time and efforts.